# $stateChangeStart remove event.preventDefault that was originally enabled

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, jquery-events

I am preventing a user from going to another page doing something like this, however, when it is time to proceed to the page I originally prevented, I get error `"transition prevented”`.

How can I remove the original prevention and allow the page to proceed? I have tried to return `false` instead of `event.preventDefault` but it didn't work. Any help please?

```
$rootScope.$on($stateChangeStart, function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (isCurrentPageCompleted === false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**First approach**

In case, that we want to allow user to go to some page, only if some data are loaded, we can use **`resolve`**

```
.state("prevented", {
    ...
    resolve: {
        someKey : { // promise, which once resolved 
                    // - then it will allow state transition                   
                    // function() { return ... }
                  }
    }
}
```

**Second approach**

But in case, that we want to redirect user, until some conditions are met, we can use some global service. There is **[a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/thAqwf1qMDULsfWFD43J?p=preview)**.

```
.factory("BreakTransition", function(){
  return { 
    ShouldWaitGlobally : true, 
  } 
})
```

Then we can have some states.

- One is default, used for redirection (`'home'`).
- Some are prevented till there is global transition enabled (`'prevented'`)
- and one could be enabler (`'enabler'`)

  .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    })
    .state('enabler', {
        url: "/enabler",
        templateUrl: 'tpl.enabler.html',
        controller: "EnablerController",
    })
    .state('prevented', {
        url: "/prevented",
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        data : {
          ShouldWaitForCompletion : true,
        },
    })

And now, until the factory value is changed, we can use this "break"

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'BreakTransition',
  function ($rootScope, $state, BreakTransition) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams 
                                            , fromState, fromParams) {
    var shouldNotWait = toState.name === "home"
    if(shouldNotWait)
    {
      return;
    }

    var isCurrentPageCompleted = BreakTransition.ShouldWaitGlobally !== true
        || (toState.data || {}).ShouldWaitForCompletion !== true;


    if (isCurrentPageCompleted === true) {
      return;
    } 

    e.preventDefault(); 
    $state.go('home');

  });
}])
```

Check that [all in action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/thAqwf1qMDULsfWFD43J?p=preview)